# Logo image gets cut when height of screen is adjusted

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the following webpage responsive but when I adjust the screen height the logo image gets cut as I decrease the height of the screen.

I am unable to find the common ground where I can set the logo image as full view and set some padding around the logo so that it doesn't get stuck to the top screen.

Below is the GIF image that describes the issue:
[image: Issue]

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

img {
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

div {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/G3WCmqLQ/icon.png">
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Add media query

Comment: most responsive sites are responsive to width rather than height - are you wanting the logo to be responsive to both width and height? if so then you either need to use media queries and put in options for all outcomes or use js to figure out which side is smaller so you can reduce your logo size accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is just change `css` of `body` from `display: flex;` to `display: inline-grid;`. Hope this will solve your issue.

```
body {
            background-color: black;
            display: inline-grid;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        img {
            height: 5em;
            width: 5em;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        div {
            background-color: #FFF;
            padding: 2em;
        }
```

And HTML is;

```
<section>
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/G3WCmqLQ/icon.png">
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: what exactly is inline-grid? It solved the problem

Comment: That's great that it solved your problem. You can explore more about display Property from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Comment: You are welcome. You should also caste up vote for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add `height: 100%` to `section`

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

div {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300">
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```